# Best way for account activation

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to create an account register page with `CakePHP 2.0` where user needs to activate it's new account by clicking on a link in the email he's received after insert `username`, `email` and `password`.

My question is how can I set an activation code inside the user record.

I thought to create a table field named `activation_code` and then to store an `hashed` version of the `username` to be sure the user can activate itself by clicking the email link with the activation key.

All the procedure is done but I don't know how can I set the `activation_code` inside the `$data['User']` object and It's not clear for me if this is a good usage of the MVC framework or I should make it in a different way.

During the user registration action I've done this but I get an error when I try to create 'activation_code' dynamically:

```
// from the UserController class
public function register () {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->data['User']['confirm_password']) {
            // here is where I get the error
            $this->data['User']['activation_key'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['email']);
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                // private method
                $this->registrationEmail ($this->data['User']['email'], $this->data['User']['username']);
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'registration', 'success'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the `activation_key` is an empty field inside my database.

So how can I create a filed dynamically from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with the method `Model::set()`, so:

```
public function register () {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->data['User']['confirm_password']) {
            $this->User->create();
            // I've used set method
            $this->User->set('activation_key', AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['email']));
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->registrationEmail ($this->data['User']['email'], $this->data['User']['username']);
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'registration', 'success'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->data['User']['activation_key']
```

should be:

```
$this->request->data['User']['activation_key']
```

(You should change all references to $this->data to the new cakephp2.0 $this->request->data)